# How to use oci_connect() only once and then include its file

Tags: php, oracle, database-connection, connection-string, oracle-call-interface

I am making a website using PHP and oracle database.
I have a connect.php file

```
<?php 
$connect_error = "We are Experiencing Some Technical Difficulty";
oci_connect("asim","asim","localhost/xe") or die($connect_error);
?>
```

i have included this file in every page!

But whenever I have to execute a query I have to do this

```
function user_exists($username){
    $conn = oci_connect("asim","asim","localhost/xe");

    $username = sanitize($username); 
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT COUNT(username)....");
    oci_execute($stmt); 
    return ($stmt > 0) ? true:false; 
}
```

I have to include the line `$conn = oci_connect("asim","asim","localhost/xe");` in every function.

**Is there a way to avoid this.**

**oci_execute** [Executes a statement previously returned from oci_parse().](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php)
and **oci_parse** needs 2 parameters one of which is [connection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the result of your first call to `oci_connect()` to a variable like so:

```
<?php 
$connect_error = "We are Experiencing Some Technical Difficulty";
$conn = oci_connect("asim","asim","localhost/xe") or die($connect_error);
?>
```

Then in all functions where you want to use that connection you can simply reference it as a [global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) using the `global` keyword:

```
function user_exists($username){
    global $conn;

    $username = sanitize($username); 
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT COUNT(username)....");
    oci_execute($stmt); 
    return ($stmt > 0) ? true:false; 
}
```